# How to add a message in the request location permission modal for an Expo React Native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo React Native app and need to add a message to the modal alert that's displayed in the app when requesting permission to use the user's location.

Apple says that it must be descriptive enough so the users understand what is the purpose of location disclosure :

"Please put why the app is requesting the user's location inside the permission modal alert so that the user will know why they are being asked to use their location."

In the app.json file I've added the following but it doesn't show in the pop-up:

```
"ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "**********",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "This app uses your location to determine the current weather conditions in your local area."
      }
    },
```

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: Are you requesting location permission from the user?

Comment: @user18309290 that's correct. I'm requesting location permissions and need to explain why in the default modal popup. This is an expo react native app.

Comment: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription seems to be deprecated: "For apps deployed to targets in iOS 11 and later, use NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription instead.". Maybe worth trying.

Comment: @user18309290 I tried that and uploaded it to TestFlight and still the same generic message in the locatation permission modal popup. I thought the string for the key "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" in "infoPlist" is what the user would see in the permission modal.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked in the app.json file. For my case I think it was the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key value pair did the trick.

```
"ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "**********",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "This app uses your location to determine the current weather conditions in your local area.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "This app uses your location to determine the current weather conditions in your local area.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "This app uses your location to determine the current weather conditions in your local area."
      }
```